# If the use of the word "Exes" being the plural of the word Ex is fine [ 2 ] How come former boy/girl friends are also described as Ex?

Tags: slang

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition copyright ©2015 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved defines the word "ex" as below:
"ex 3  (ĕks)
Share:
n. 
Slang
A former spouse or partner."
x 2  (ĕks)
Share:
n.
Exes:PLURAL:
The letter x.
tr.v. exed, ex·ing, ex·es
To delete or cross out: He exed each item off the to-do list."
[https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=exes&submit.x=20&submit.y=34]

I have two questions here. {1} is if the plural "Exes" is being normally used say in poetry or short stories etc. **Doesn't it look odd?** For example"She called all her  "Exes" on her birthday party this times." One may like to substitute it with the term "ex-spouses". This query is raised by me **as a writer/poet.** 
{ 2 } The above dictionary although restricts the use of the above word to only a former spouse, it is **being used for a former boy/girl friend or for a former live-in-relation.** 
Do we justify this usage. Even I read a former GP being referred to as my ex- GP, and a former maid-servant as ex-maid.

Comment: (1) Language doesn't operate on the principle of what looks odd or doesn't. People say what they say and dictionaries dutifully record the facts.  (2) it's been used for ex-bf/ex-gf for as long as I've been aware of the word, and in fact the very dictionary definition you quote gives "a former spouse *or partner*", which means AHD has seen it too. So, in sum: no, it doesn't look odd, because everyone uses it this way, and no, it is not restricted to ex-spouses.

Comment: Yes I do appreciate the effort, although the term partner per say does not include Bfs  / Gfs . Are they partners really? Not so in my opinion. And how do we justify its application to say an ex GP or an ex maid servant.

Comment: The term *partner* does include BFs and GFs and in general "significant others"; that is its purpose in life: to designate romantic relations who are not spouses. Also, dictionaries don't *license* usage, they *record* it, and the fact of the matter is the use of "ex" for BF/GF is ubiquitous, so it *does* mean that, if "the meaning of a word" signifies anything at all. If you personally need a dictionary to license usage, I suggest you check out a few more to identify one which more explicitly covers this issue. As to ex-GP and ex-maid: that's the prefix *ex-*, not the (standalone) word *ex*.

Comment: In fact, if you [cross-reference the word *partner* in AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=girlfriend), the very dictionary you quote for the definition of ex, you'll find it explicitly covers boyfriends and girlfriends: *c. A domestic partner* / *d. A lover* . If you're still unconvinced, consider this: if AHD simply intended *partner* as a synonym for *spouse*, what was the purpose of stating *spouse **or** partner* when *spouse* alone would have sufficed?

Answer (score 2):

"Exes" are defined in your question as "A former spouse or partner."  This definition already covers spouses, and girl- and boy-friends (live-in or not).

In modern English, "partner" is an umbrella term to mean any romantic partner, of any gender, with or without marriage.

[Partner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/partner)

> - A partner in a ​company is one of the owners.
> - A person’s partner can also be the ​person to whom someone is ​married, or to whom the ​person is not ​married but with whom they
>     have a ​close ​relationship.

### Common usages

In American English, I hear the following terms in common use:

- ex-husband
- ex-wife
- ex
- ex-girlfriend
- ex-boyfriend
- former lover (typically only refers to couples who were never married)

"Ex-spouse" would be understood, but is an usual construction and would sound odd to a native speaker.

"Ex-partner" is uncommon, and tends to refer to a former business partner (first definition above), rather than a former lover.  Context, however, can clarify this.

Comment: My kudos. You did a wonderful job wow. Thanks a ton, best wishes. I shall look forward to listen from you more often.